# R strucplot residuals legend font

Tags: r, legend

Is there any way to change the font of a residuals-based legend in the strucplot framework? I've created labels in mosaic plots and extended association plots with serif font by specifying the font in the labeling and labeling_args parameters. This makes the text in the plot is in serif font. I have tried to make the residuals-based legend in serif font too by calling par(family="serif") at the start of the code and the end, but this does not make the legend text serif.

My data is a 6x3 array with row and column names:

```
   names<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
   y<-c(340, 37, 110, 17, 71)
   z<-c(720, 14, 6, 141, 120)
   x<-data.frame(names, y, z, row.names=TRUE); x
   attach(x)
   library(vcd)
```

The code I am using is:

```
   op<-par(family="serif")
   my.largs<-list(gp_labels=gpar(fontsize=12, fontfamily="serif"), gp_varnames=gpar(fontsize=12, fontfamily="serif", fontface="italic"))

   names(dimnames(x))<-c("Name1", "Name2")
   mosaic(t(x), gp=shading_Friendly, compress=FALSE, gp_text=gpar(fontsize=12, fontfamily="serif"), labeling=labeling_values, labeling_args=my.largs)
   par(op)
```

I'm using Rstudio (Version 0.97.551) through R (Version 2.14.0) on a Mac OS X 10.6. I'm a relatively inexperienced R user. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please make your example reproducible, we don't know what x.matrix looks like, and that both raster and grid packages are required

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and apologies - I have edited original question to make example reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried specifying the font via arguments such as legend(), legend_args(), and legend_resbased() but none worked. The author of the vcd package has since informed me that it is not currently possible to specify the font of a residuals legend for the vcd plots as they are now, but he will try to add such a parameter in the upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

incorporating the font in `mosaic()` using `legend_resbased()` works now